# How to download and run the Windows version of USBView (the USB device viewer)

Tags: windows, usb, download, hardware-detection

I installed the Windows version of USBView (the USB device viewer) as part of a much-bigger set of tools. The installer installed a deep tree of many directories onto my PC, but it didn't seem to add USBView to my Start menu. It's not at all obvious how to launch the utility.

What's the correct way to download and install the Windows version of USBView (the USB device viewer)? Also, how can I run it?

Comment: The Linux version of this question is: ["How can I install the Linux version of USBView (the USB device viewer)?"](http://superuser.com/questions/1180854/how-can-i-download-usbview-the-usb-device-viewer-for-linux)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no need to install any Microsoft DDK or SDK or any other Microsoft development kit. There is a freeware derivative, maintained by Uwe Sieber, named [USBTreeView](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html). Go there, download, unzip, and just run. It is only ~300 kilobytes. It is based on the same Microsoft open-source code, but is much better, with more functionality, and with fewer bugs.

Comment: +1.  I looked into the matter further today, and I discovered that Microsoft's original [USBView source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) is distributed under the [Microsoft Public License](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/LICENSE), which is an OSI-approved open-source license.  And USBTreeView is a derivative of USBView.  Cool.

Comment: @unforgettableid, thanks for your nice edit. To add, the USBTreeView has a very useful feature: it is able to "restart device", and "reset port", at any point of USB tree, which is extremely useful when some USB hubs hang up after failing to deal with some unstable USB devices. I only wish that the tool can incorporate other TEST modes on ports, which would be very useful for bring-up/debug devices and evaluate signal integrity.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you email Uwe and ask him to please add the feature?  :)  `mail` at `uwe-sieber` dot `de` is his email address.

Comment: Can I see device power consumption with USBView/USBTreeView?

Comment: @Suncatcher, you cannot see actual power consumption (because USB doesn't specify standard means to measure the port current), but you can see how much current the device declares to need. It is encoded in main descriptor field, which you can read with USBView. You need to look it up from USB specifications, bMaxPower.

Answer (score 6):

## How to download

Download and install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx).  This set of tools takes up a few hundred megabytes, but it also includes other useful tools like WinDbg.

Unfortunately, the Debugging Tools installer won't add USBView to your Start menu.  But you can run the tool manually.

## How to run

By default, the 64-bit version of USBView will get installed to:

"\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\usbview.exe"

Go there and run it.

## Source code

If you want the USBView source code, go [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview).

Comment: This should be the correct answer, seeing as it actually _answers the question_!

Comment: I suppose so.  OK, fine; I've moved the checkmark.