# How can I install the Linux version of USBView (the USB device viewer)?

Tags: linux, usb, download, hardware-detection

Greg Kroah-Hartman writes that the Linux version of USBView is a GTK program that "displays the topography of the devices that are plugged into the USB bus on a Linux machine. It also displays information on each of the devices. This can be useful to determine if a device is working properly or not."

How can I install the Linux version of USBView?

Comment: The Windows version of this question is: ["How can I download and run USBView (the USB device viewer) for Windows?"](http://superuser.com/questions/1180850/how-can-i-download-and-run-usbview-the-usb-device-viewer-for-windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most Linux software, you should normally not download USBView using a web browser. Instead, you should normally use an easy-to-use graphical front-end to your distribution's package management system — e.g. the Ubuntu Software Center or similar. This tool can automatically download and install USBView in one step.

On Ubuntu:

- USBView is in the `usbview` package.

If you're running Ubuntu on a headless device, you can use lsusb or lshw instead:

- lsusb is in the `usbutils` package.
- lshw is in the `lshw` package.