# WiFi USB adapter works in just one slot of my laptop

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, laptop, usb

I have a TP-Link WiFi USB adapter (model: TP-WN725N) which I use with a low end HP laptop (model HP 650, four years old). The OS of the laptop is Debian 9.4. I used to plug the WiFi adapter to the first left side USB slot of the laptop, and it works fine. Today I happen to plug the adapter on a different USB slot and noticed that I was unable to connect to the wireless network I've always used (WPA2 authentication method). Every time I got the following message in my logs:

```
R8188EU: sta recv deauth reason code(15)
```

Searching the Internet and looking at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347588/tp-link-wifi-usb-adapter-keeps-dropping-connection-immediately-on-debian-8), it could be a driver problem or a cheap hardware issue, but why it works in the other slot then? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: It is not a driver problem, if it were a driver problem, the device wouldn't work in any USB port.  You are plugging the device into a USB 2.0+ port I presume?

Comment: Yes, it's a USB 2.0 port. The technical specifications reports all USB slots as 2.0 compliant.

Comment: Do other USB devices work well regardless of the slot they use?

Comment: I've only used USB pen drives, but they all worked flawlessly.

Comment: Likely there are several layers of drivers servicing the networking device, and it could be some security associations issue or something. To rule out any USB-level issues, you need to examine USB kernel logs when the device is plugged into "bad" port, or  have some Linux version of USBTreeViewer, https://superuser.com/q/1180854/620011