# Computer regularly stops recognizing mouse after unplugging and replugging it in

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, keyboard, mouse

After I unplug my mouse/keyboard (USB, wireless), my computer stops recognizing it.

This does not happen *every* time, however, it happens often enough that I am seriously considering reimaging my computer. The workaround I've found so far is rebooting, but at this rate I might need to hire a Microsoft Certified Reboot Technician.

The equipment:

- Dell Inspiron D09S running Windows 10. All drivers are up to date, and to my knowledge, Windows is too.
- Logitech K350 combined wireless mouse and keyboard (goes to USB)

Comment: Which port do you use for K350 dongle transceiver? Front? Rear? USB 3.0?

Comment: @Ali I've tried all the ports. I mostly use front for the keyboard/mouse though

Comment: Ok, so any interference with USB 3.0 2.5GHz carrier rules out. Did you try the K350 in some other computer? Did you try USBTreeView to see how far the USB controller gets in "recognizing" the dongle?  https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011

Comment: I've tried the K350 with other computers, and it works fine. (Even after plugging and disconnecting). I'm fairly sure it's not the K350, at least not directly. However, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue with another keyboard and mouse (wired Dell keyboard that came with the computer, and wireless Logitech M325).

Comment: If I remember correctly, however, I tried checking the tree view once (with a new mouse/keyboard, during the problem), but the K350 wasn't recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the auto-installed drivers weren't good enough.  I went to the [K350 product page](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-keyboard-k350) and downloaded [SetPoint](https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/mouse/SetPoint6.67.83_smart.exe).  When I next plugged my K350 in, it installed a bunch of new drivers, and my problem seems to have been resolved.

Comment: My first thoughts were about the drivers. So that's great that it helped.