# How to find what dongles are for

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, dongle

I have a box of the little thumbnail sized dongles (well, just six) and I'm trying to find out which belong to two wireless keyboards I'd like to give away, but I'm having no luck getting the keyboards to work with any of them.    I know a couple might be for mice, fitbits and I'm sure at least one of these was for one of the keyboards. The friend I'm trying to give the keyboards to is not a techie and won't be able to figure out how to use them without their original USB dongles.

Is there a smarter way to look at the dongles with an app or something to see what they were originally for?

Answer (score 2):

There are several viewers of plugged USB devices available.

One is [USBTreeview](https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011), but it might need some technical skills to digest descriptor information.

Other useful utilities can be found on [NirSoft site](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/index.html#system_utils), see USB section. But it will be still challenging to identify commercial designator/name for your dongles.

Comment: YES!  this works perfectly for my purposes - I can stop dorking around with the fitbit and certain mouse ones - it appears in the USBTreeview displays at the very bottom for some of them.  Exactly what I was looking for!!  You rock!