# Semi-faulty RAID 5 enclosure: Replace or fix

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, raid, freeze

I have two identical model external 4-bay RAID enclosure systems.  Both are configured to USB 3.0 RAID-5 containing the same number and model hard drives.  Both are functioning in that I'm able to access all the data I need to, however, one of the two has been acting up for awhile now.

One of them tends to brain freeze every once and awhile.  For instance, I'll be working on a file and then I'll go to save my work and the whole application will freeze for a solid minute because it is waiting on the drive to respond.  During this frozen time, if I go to My Computer and try to view the drive, Explorer too will freeze, however the other RAID drive it can access just fine.  If I allow Explorer to freeze and wait for the drive, both Explorer and the application that is attempting to save the file will both simultaneously unfreeze and continue normal operation after the normal minute or so of waiting.  This seems to happen many multiple times in an hour, it's been going on for a few months now and I've decided I can't take it any longer.

A few things I've tried with no success:

Switching the USB cables between the two enclosures (no change)
Switching the USB ports each enclosures use (no change)
Scanning (and repairing) for bad sectors and errors (none found)
Defragmentation (no change)

I'm left with two options and I'm looking for guidance, and I'm willing to do both:

1. Fix the issue (I'm preferring this route) if it can be fixed and if
   there are additional suggestions that anyone might have.
2. Replace the enclosure with a new one (I'd prefer to avoid the cost if I can, but not against it).  With a 4-drive RAID-5 setup, is this doable?  Can I just remove the drives and plug them into the new enclosure exactly as I had them there?  (Assume the new enclosure is the same exact model)  Or would I have to backup and use a fresh setup on the new enclosure? (I'd really hate that since I'd have to purchase additional hard drives to accomplish that)  And are there any additional considerations in this area?

Comment: " Can I just remove the drives and plug them into the new enclosure exactly as I had them there? " Doubtful as each raid controller is slightly different on how it configures the drives, be sure you have a backup of data before doing anything. I could be only one drive in the array that is causing all the problems.

Comment: I was also afraid of that, it possibly being one of the drives. I would hope that the RAID would identify and recognize that and inform me to replace the bad drive :/ Problem is, I don't know which one and if that's even the cause.

Comment: Did you check if LPM (Link Power Management) is enabled/disabled on the drives? Also check for firmware differences (PID/DID numbers).

Comment: LPM is not even an option that I can choose, so I assume it's disabled. I cannot see any numbers in device manager that would suggest firmware or PID or DID numbers.

Comment: @codemann8, to see USB descriptor details and/or differences, you need to use USB viewers, like this one, https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011