# How to identify USB Ports in Device Manager?

Tags: windows, usb, device-manager

How can I identify which items in Device Manager indicate actual, physical **USB Ports**?

Answer (score 4):

I usually use [USBTreeView](https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011) utility to see all USB connections, and then plug a USB device and see which port it will appear on.

Answer (score 0):

On PCs, USB 'buses' are referred to as hubs. Identify your USB devices in Sound, Video and Game Controllers (or alternatively directly on the USB hubs)
You can have a look at Device Manager-right click the usb device and find the port location.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fc2011f7-c84a-43d7-8a11-821aff3a82ab/a-little-question-about-usb-ports-in-windows7?forum=w7itprohardware

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it's still relevant in Windows 11.

A nice answer is provided by Intel in [this article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005622/software/chipset-software.html).

You can use Device Manager to View "Devices by connection", so that you can see which device is on which hub.

I needed this information because I had to turn off Energy Saving on the port that my USB-C power supply was connected to.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1226416)