# My usb 2.0 port suddenly stopped working (but it gives out power) and my usb 3.0 ports only read devices with usb 3.0

Tags: usb, laptop, drivers

I have a Legion Y520-15IKBN Laptop (Lenovo) - Type 80WK laptop and my usb 2.0 port does not read any devices but apparently gives out power. On the other hand, my usb 3.0 ports only read devices with usb 3.0.
I literally tried everything... changed windows ... deleted recently installed updates ... updated drivers ... installed the old drivers again ... disabled power suspension for usb ... my battery is in good health but I tried taking the battery out for 1 hour and even holding the power button ... I don't know what else should I do?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "changed Windows"?  Have you considered the possability of hardware failure, since USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 drivers are built-into Windows?

Comment: Sorry, I meant reinstalling ... To be honest that's my guess too but I don't understand it ... they have a power outlet and even usb 3.0 port works fine with devices which have usb 3.0. How can it be a hardware failure?

Comment: to check your USB connectivity you can use a nice utility https://superuser.com/a/1181052/620011 Or start with Windows Device Manager to see if there are any "yellow bangs" (there should be none). Append your question with what you see with these tools.

Comment: Are you saying that no mice nor keyboard work in all three available USB-A ports?

Answer (score 1):

Test if the Windows OS or its drivers *are* at fault, boot from a live USB (e.g., [Win PE](https://www.minitool.com/lib/windows-pe.html)/[WinRE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference?view=windows-11), [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install)).

- If the ports work properly from the other OS, **fix Windows**, using [SFC and DISM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e) or [reinstall from ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
- If the ports **do not** work properly under the alternate OS, then you have a **hardware** issue.

  - Either have the machine repaired
  - Or try using a USB hub in the 3.0 ports to see if that lets a USB 2.0 device work.

Comment: Thank you for your response ... I've already tried live USB (ubuntu) ... but I don't know what exactly I should do to get certain that my USB 2.0 ports are not working when I am on live USB ... to be honest I am starting to come around to the idea of hardware failure.

Comment: "I don't know what exactly I should do to get certain that my USB 2.0 ports are not working..." plug in a USB flash drive, mouse dongle or other device -- either it works, or not. Possible exception: some external HDD may need more power than a marginal USB port could provide.